# How to run the Node API tests for browser-perf

Tags: node.js, performance-testing, protractor

I am trying to configure browser-perf for measuring browser performance metrics. I am able to run it via commandline using

```
browser-perf --selenium=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub http://yourwebsite.com
```

However, I want to configure the [Node Module API](https://github.com/axemclion/browser-perf/wiki/Node-Module---API) for browser-perf.

Following is the issue:
1. I am not able to find a command to execute the node API browser-perf tests. 
2. Also, where do I place the call to browserPerf() - In conf OR in spec ??

If someone can provide steps for the Node API setup, that would be really helpful!

PS: I found `protractor-perf conf.js` command is used to protractor-perf tests. Just not able to find something similar for browser-perf!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below link gives all the necessary steps to setup and execute browser-perf tests

https://gist.github.com/axemclion/9594795